# How to make cell adjust to text view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm making a social media app and I want the cell to conform to the textview. What I believe the problem is, is that the text view won't conform to the text. Here is what the cell looks like... https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4gBy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UITextView does not magically size itself to its text. A UILabel does! If you can use a label instead, use it. Otherwise, it is up to *you* to keep resizing the UITextView so that its height (or, if you're using self-sizing cells based on internal constraints, its height constraint) matches the height of its `contentSize`.

Comment: There are lots of other duplicates to this. The point of marking as a duplicate is that you should search before asking. Now search.